# Simulate high CPU, network etc using cmd on Windows 10?

Tags: terminal, windows-10, load, cpu-usage, simulate

I need to simulate high load on CPU, memory, disk, network on my Windows 10 for project purposes (progressively higher upto 100%).

So far I've been able to find VB scripts and tools (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2012/10/26/tools-to-simulate-cpu-memory-disk-load/) that work to this end. Is there a way I can do this in the command terminal?

Is there something in Windows similar to using /dev/null/ on linux shell where the % usage can be specified as well?

Comment: but the provided link also have command line tools, `consume -cpu-time -time 5`

Comment: yes it does, I'm looking for something where I can preferably specify the % spike as well. Also looking for a way to simulating network usage.